# Query Web Api with Rest Framework

Tags: json, rest

I am brand new to using web API's, and I'm trying to call a very specific API but I can't seem to query it. I am trying to call https://www.transparency.treasury.gov/article/api-debt-to-the-penny, and pass in a certain date. When I call https://www.transparency.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/od/debt_to_penny?q=data_date:2020-07-20, however, I get
{"error":"Invalid Query Param","message":"Invalid query parameter 'q' with value '[data_date:{2020-
07-
20}]'.  For more information please see the documentation."}

What am I doing wrong? How can I call a certain date? I am assuming that it is Rest since I was able to successfully say ?sort=data_date at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you are mentioning is IMHO a bad example and it has moved to

https://fiscaldata.treasury.gov/datasets/debt-to-the-penny/

Usually the parameter would be given in the form:

https://www.transparency.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/od/debt_to_penny?data_date=2020-07-20

which means ?key1=value1&key2=value2

In the new API they describe that the parameters should be given in the form

https://www.transparency.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v2/accounting/od/debt_to_penny?filter=record_date:gte:20200727

which however at the time of writing brings a 502 Bad Gateway error like the example url mentioned in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

@Christian - thanks for pointing out the API's new home.

When including date as a parameter, dashes must separate the different date units.

The following example should work: https://www.transparency.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v2/accounting/od/debt_to_penny?filter=record_date:gte:2020-07-27

Also want to highlight that the system allows for operators such as greater than, less than etc. As shown in the example Christian included.

Would've commented on Christian's post, but don't have the reputation yet. Good luck with your first API Call, @Sathvik!.